# Spring boot multitenancy , where one tenant connects to multiple schema

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I am creating a spring boot application which should support multitenancy, separate database approach. Each tenant would be using multiple schema and it would be loaded dynamically from some config file. The tenants and schemas would be something like this,

Tenant 1:

```
url : dbc:mysql://dns1/abc_schema
username : sa
password : sa

url : dbc:mysql://dns1/pqr_schema
username : sa
password : sa

url : dbc:mysql://dns1/xyz_schema
username : sa
password : sa
```

Tenant 2:

```
url : dbc:mysql://dns2/abc_schema
username : sa
password : sa

url : dbc:mysql://dns2/pqr_schema
username : sa
password : sa

url : dbc:mysql://dns2/xyz_schema
username : sa
password : sa
```

Currently its a single tenant application where all the 3 schema have been mentioned in application.properties. All the database instance have the same schema names,but in different db instances. Right now, there are 3 separate config file with @ configuration to load the tables on application start up.

I am converting this application to a multitenant one. The steps for implementing a multitenant application with tenants having a single schema is clear, but I have multiple schema for a tenant. So, the question is when implementing  `AbstractDataSourceBasedMultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl` class ,`selectDataSource()` function returns a single Datasource. But how to pass the multiple schemas in it?

```
@Override
    protected DataSource selectDataSource(String tenantIdentifier) {
        if (isInitialLoad) {
            isInitialLoad = false;
            TenantDataSource tenantDataSource = context.getBean(TenantDataSource.class);
            map.putAll(tenantDataSource.getAll());
        }
        return map.get(tenantIdentifier);
    }
```

Thanks in advance,
Schelz

Comment: check out this https://www.baeldung.com/spring-abstract-routing-data-source

Answer (score 0):

This is just given approach not exactly solution

Define Router as seen below after that you can set in configuration

```
public class ClientDataSourceRouter
  extends AbstractRoutingDataSource {

    @Override
    protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {
        return ClientDatabaseContextHolder.getClientDatabase();
    }
}
```

We need a Map of contexts to DataSource objects to configure our AbstractRoutingDataSource. We can also specify a default DataSource to use if there is no context set.

The DataSources we use can come from anywhere but will typically be either created at runtime or looked up using JNDI:

@Configuration
public class RoutingTestConfiguration {

```
@Bean
public DataSource clientDatasource() {
    Map<Object, Object> targetDataSources = new HashMap<>();
    DataSource clientADatasource = clientADatasource();
    DataSource clientBDatasource = clientBDatasource();
    targetDataSources.put(ClientDatabase.CLIENT_A, 
      clientADatasource);
    targetDataSources.put(ClientDatabase.CLIENT_B, 
      clientBDatasource);

    ClientDataSourceRouter clientRoutingDatasource 
      = new ClientDataSourceRouter();
    clientRoutingDatasource.setTargetDataSources(targetDataSources);
    clientRoutingDatasource.setDefaultTargetDataSource(clientADatasource);
    return clientRoutingDatasource;
}

// ...
```

}

[check out more information - baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-abstract-routing-data-source)

Another solution is defined as seen below

**Multitenant Models**
There are several models to achieve multitenancy in an application:

- Database per Tenant
  Each Tenant has its own database and is isolated from other tenants.
- **Shared database, Separate Schema** ( this is what we looking for)

All Tenants share a database, but have their own database schemas and their own tables.

- Shared Database, Shared Schema
  All Tenants share a database and tables. Every table has a Column with the Tenant Identifier, that shows the owner of the row.

example :

```
@Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {

        AbstractRoutingDataSource dataSource = new TenantAwareRoutingSource();

        Map<Object,Object> targetDataSources = new HashMap<>();

        targetDataSources.put("TenantOne", tenantOne());
        targetDataSources.put("TenantTwo", tenantTwo());

        dataSource.setTargetDataSources(targetDataSources);

        dataSource.afterPropertiesSet();

        return dataSource;
    }

    public DataSource tenantOne() {

        HikariDataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource();

        dataSource.setInitializationFailTimeout(0);
        dataSource.setMaximumPoolSize(5);
        dataSource.setDataSourceClassName("org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource");
        dataSource.addDataSourceProperty("url", "jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/sampledb");
        dataSource.addDataSourceProperty("user", "philipp");
        dataSource.addDataSourceProperty("password", "test_pwd");
 **we need to find datasource.setschema is exist or not**
        return dataSource;
    }

    public DataSource tenantTwo() {

        HikariDataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource();

        dataSource.setInitializationFailTimeout(0);
        dataSource.setMaximumPoolSize(5);
        dataSource.setDataSourceClassName("org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource");
        dataSource.addDataSourceProperty("url", "jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/sampledb1");
        dataSource.addDataSourceProperty("user", "philipp");
        dataSource.addDataSourceProperty("password", "test_pwd");
** we need to find datasource.setschema is exist or not**
        return dataSource;
    }
```

or there is just one option also exist

tenant One

```
spring.datasource.first.url=jdbc:postgresql://my_url:my_port/my_other_stuff
spring.datasource.first.username=my_user_name
spring.datasource.first.password=my_password
spring.datasource.first.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.first.schema=A
```

tenant two

```
spring.source.second.url=jdbc:postgresql://my_url:my_port/my_other_stuff
spring.source.second.username=my_user_name
spring.source.second.password=my_password
spring.source.second.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.source.second.schema = B
```

And then create PropertySource classes for each and then it will be setted by spring and after that you can use them

```
 @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "datasource.first")
@Bean
@Primary
public DataSource dataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder
        .create()
        .build();
}
```

check also this link
[enter link description here](https://bytefish.de/blog/spring_boot_multitenancy/)

Comment: Thanks. Here for `targetDataSources.put(ClientDatabase.CLIENT_A, 
      clientADatasource);` , clientADatasource can be only one single datasource right? But for me I have client_A pointing to 3 datasources. Is it possible to give a list of datasources for CLIENT_A?

Comment: nope because datasource means just one data source thats why they putting all data source to map and setting setTargetDatasources when at run time for example location changed you can set datasource to another or its up to your scenario

Comment: ok but some API calls make use of both schema of a single tenant to arrive at a result. so, how to resolve that if we can make connection to just one data source?

Comment: Actually the multitenant approach I am using is **separate database** for each tenant. But its just that a single tenant has to take data from different schema in a single RDS instance.